# Oracle Client Silent Install Fails

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, installation, client

I'm creating an automated package in PDQ Deploy which installs the Oracle client, and some patches. Step 1 copies the staging files to the target, which completes successfully. Step 2 attempts to install the Oracle Client silently, and hangs indefinitely.

These are the commands I'm using for the silent install, any idea what's going wrong here? I'm using a template that I found [here](http://www.dadbm.com/oracle-database-client-silent-installation-response-file/). The Oracle client version is 11.2.0.4.0

```
cd C:\PDQStaging\Oracle\64bit\client\
.\setup.exe -silent -debug -force -waitforcompletion  
FROM_LOCATION=C:\PDQStaging\Oracle\64bit\client\stage\products.xml 
oracle.install.client.installType=”Administrator” 
ORACLE_HOME=”C:\Oracle\64bit\product\11.2.0\Client” 
ORACLE_HOME_NAME=”OraClient11g_Home1″ 
ORACLE_BASE=”C:\Oracle” 
DECLINE_SECURITY_UPDATES=true
```

I wanted to avoid using a response file since the above seems like a simpler solution.

Comment: Prob. an error while copying here, but some of your quotes are the wrong character `”` vs `"`.

Comment: To determine whether a silent or response file mode installation succeeds or fails, check the `silentInstallActionsdate_time.log` file, located in the `C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs` directory

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it using a response file, after all.

```
C:\PDQStaging\Oracle\64bit\client\setup.exe -silent -nowelcome -nowait -responseFile C:\PDQStaging\Oracle\64bit\client_install.rsp
```

Comment: Welcome on the DBA SE! Thanks, nice answer. You can accept also your own post, click the pipe icon to the left.

Comment: And what was in the response file?